# Is there difference between _xx.html and xx.html?

Tags: python, html, django, model-view-controller

When I read the source code of a project:

[image]

I find there is some `_xxx.html`, why the author give the `_`? is there extraordinary should pay attention?

---

**EDIT**

This is in the Python Django project.

Comment: I've updated my answer below to be a bit more specific since you updated the question w/ the framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The template files are probably partials, or rather templates that aren't meant to be served directly, but rather within another template. Django doesn't seem to have anything specific about how to name your partials, but it does look like it's common practice in MVC frameworks to use `_xx.html` as a naming convention.

ASP.Net: [ASP.NET MVC3 Partial View naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750953/asp-net-mvc3-partial-view-naming-convention)

RoR: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Django: https://oncampus.oberlin.edu/webteam/2012/09/architecture-django-templates